# Select the rows of the group based on 2 conditions but combine the unique categories of that group

Tags: pandas, pyspark, jupyter

I have a table like below

```
ID    Date         Category      Cycles      
--------------------------------------------
RYI19  6/12/2018    TEMPERATURE   1567    y   
RYI19  6/13/2018    VOLUME        1620    n
RYI19  6/25/2018    AREA          1890    y    
RYI19  6/28/2018    TEMPERATURE   1435    y
TYI23  5/10/2020    LENGTH        1567    Y
TYI23  6/12/2020    LENGTH        1678    Y
TYI23  6/13/2020    LENGTH        1689    n
```

Before my only condition was to select first from the group

So I wrote this code:

```
 select 
     ID, date 
 from 
     (select 
          ID, date, 
          row_number() over(partition by ID order by date) rn 
      from 
          table1) t1 
where 
    rn = 1
```

Now I have 2 additional columns and 2 conditions if the group is within 2 days and cycles less than 100, don't consider that record. Ideally the cycles need to increase as date increases but in case it is smaller then only date condition of 2 days need to be considered for records to select or not. as far as the category is considered it needs to combine all unique categories when the records are not considered. If it is same dates then one of them needs to be picked.

```
ID     Date         Category              Cycles      
-------------------------------------------------
RYI19  6/12/2018    TEMPERATURE & VOLUME   1567      
RYI19  6/25/2018    AREA                   1890        
RYI19  6/28/2018    TEMPERATURE            1435   
TYI23  5/10/2020    LENGTH                 1567   
TYI23  6/12/2020    LENGTH                 1678
```

I need to make sure to have only unique category in the field-Note that last record did not have LENGTH in the category twice.

Edit:
Adding rules clearly
1)If the dates are within 2 days or the cycles are within 100 cycles then remove the non- VOLUME record but if the categories are both VOLUME or both NON VOLUME records then display the prior date record.

2)If the temperature category is 10 days prior to the volume record then also consider the volume record only that is flag the temperature record to be removed/filtered.

3)If one of dates is in December then consider 30 days difference if the categories are different.

```
  ID      Date       Category     Cycles
 RPI100   8/7/2020   Volume       4327
 RPI100   8/18/2020  TEMPERATURE  4300
 RDY234   6/1/2020   VOLUME       7014
 RDY234   6/4/2020   TEMERATURE   7014
 PDI23    8/3/2020   VOLUME       9799
 PDI23    9/28/2020  TEMERATURE   12968
 PDI23    10/6/2020  VOLUME       13398
 F128     2/25/2020  TEMERATURE   9875
 YU567    12/2/2020  VOLUME       7403
 YU567    12/3/2020  VOLUME       7436
 RTY78    8/17/2020  STATE        3198
 TYI12    1/27/2020  VOLUME       6145
 RPI145   12/16/2019 VOLUME       2110
 RPI145    1/23/2020 TEMPERATURE  0
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using this in a Pandas dataframe?

Comment: yes as a pandas dataframe

Comment: Just to confirm: when you want to group given rows, do you want to take the first value for `Date` & `Cycle`? (As you did for the `TEMPERATURE & VOLUME` row)

Comment: Also, can you clarify the conditions dealing with "cycles less than 100"?
what should happen if the difference between the two dates is less than 2 but the difference between the cycles is > 100?

Comment: Edited example explains what rules are applied

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick

```py
df.groupby(['id', 'date', 'cycles']).agg({"Category": " & ".join})
```

Comment: How do I make sure the date conditions and the cycles condition to be satisfied and also category needs to have only unique values too